# PL / SQL difference between to dates in 'HH24:MI:SS'

Tags: plsql, difference

I am trying to calculate the difference between to dates.
The date is in the format dd:mm:yyyy HH:MI:SS and the solution should be in HH:MI:SS. But I only get ",xxxxxx".

The code I tried:

`

```
DECLARE
    ln_date1   DATE;
    ln_date2   DATE;
    ln_diff    NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR cr_example IN (  SELECT example_date
                           FROM tabelle
                          WHERE id = 1 AND example_date <= '13.12.2022'
                       ORDER BY example_date DESC
                          FETCH FIRST 40 ROWS ONLY)
    LOOP
        SELECT s.date1, s.date2
          INTO ln_date1, ln_date2
          FROM tabelle1 s
         WHERE example_date = cr_example.example_date;

        ln_diff := ln_date2 - ln_date1;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Difference: ' || ln_diff);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

`

Output:

`Difference: ,0742708333333333333333333333333333333333`

Dont know how to solve the issue, hoping anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

SOLUTION:

Thanks to William Robertson for noticing that ,0742708333333333333333333333333333333333 is in days.

To convert it in HH:MIN:SS you can use:

```
ln_diff := ln_date2 - ln_date1;

ln_hours := FLOOR (ln_diff * 24);
ln_minutes := FLOOR ((ln_diff * 24 - ln_hours) * 60);
ln_seconds :=
ROUND ((((ln_diff * 24 - ln_hours) * 60) - ln_minutes) * 60);

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
ln_hours || ':' || ln_minutes || ':' || ln_seconds || ':');
```

Comment: The difference between dates is given as a number of days. 0.07427 days is 01:46:57. Does that match with your sample data?

Comment: Glad that helped :) You can also use `numtodsinterval(date2-date1,'DAY')` to get an interval value which you can then format further (e.g. by casting to `interval day(1) to second(0)`), or else add it to trunc(sysdate) and format the result as `HH24:MI:SS`.